# can't we return list in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm just started learning python..
How to return list?
Is here any error in code.?

```
def fibonocci(x,i):
    if len(lst)>=x:
        return lst
    v=lst[i-1]+lst[i-2]
    lst.append(v)
    fibonocci(x,i+1)

n=int(input("Enter a number: "))
lst=[0,1]
print(fibonocci(n,2))
```

Comment: You *can*, but in this case you simply *don't*.

Comment: Why only in this case?

Comment: I mean what is the scenario making this to can not return..?

Comment: There's nothing that makes it *"can not return"*, but you **don't actually `return`**. It's not a fundamental problem, just something you haven't done.

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything in case `len(lst) < x`.

You should change `fibonocci(x, i+1)` to `return fibonocci(x, i+1)`.

Comment: it is a function call not a return stmt.

Comment: "return lst" is there in if loop! plz see once.